# How to persist a hashmap (map) using gwt RequestFactory mechanism?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jpa, requestfactory

I've got a domain object named Person. This domain object has a map field which handles person relationship where key is the name of the targeted person and value is the Person object.

Here is the class:

```
public class Person 
{
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Person> relationships;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @ManyToMany(...)
    @MapKey(name="name")
    public Map<String, Person> getRelationships() 
    { 
        return relationships; 
    }

    public void setRelationships(Map<String, Person> relationships) 
    { 
        this.relationships = relationships; 
    }
}
```

Using GWT RequestFactory mechanism, how to persist this map which is defined like it with hibernate ?

Comment: Just for clarity, can I phrase your question as "How can I persist a hashmap in db using hibernate""

Comment: Are you doing this in client package or server?

Comment: I want to use this mechanism : http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html but it seems that I can't map a hashmap in proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum... I think there's no way to do it... (but I'm opened to any workaround)

An issue has been created here : 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5524&q=requestfactory&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

star it if you want these feature to be added.